Net salary calculation for TVLE-13 65% PhD offer in Münster
I have received a PhD offer in Münster with a pay grade of TVLE-13 65% in 2024. How much net salary I should be expecting after all deductions?
Actually I have another PhD offer from USA with tuition waiver and 25000 USD stipend in Johnson city, Tennessee. I wanted to know how it compares in salary perspective as the research area is almost similar (I only applied for my specific research areas) and both professors are quite friendly (as far I have interacted).
I am 27, single with no kids if it matters for the tax calculation.

I kinda think the personal finance stack is a better target for this.

You'll also owe tax on your US stipend, so don't forget to calculate that as well.

There is a website to calculate TVöD and TVL Salaries: https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/allg?id=tv-l&g=E_13&s=1&zv=VBL&z=65&zulage=&stkl=1&r=&zkf=&kk=15.5%25, looks like you would end up with aroun 1800 € net per month in the first year.

I already entered 65% and TVL 13, there is a table at the bottom that shows the salaries, with the tiers. If you just start you will be in tier 1, after 1 year in tier 2 and after 2 more in tier 3 and so on.

More info can be found in the answers to the linked duplicate question.

@BryanKrause - seems unlikely their stipend will exceed $120,000. They will need to file a 1040 but are unlikely to owe anything to the US.

@JonCuster Why $120k?

@BryanKrause - IRS Publication 54 (https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p54.pdf) suggests at first glance that up to $120,000 in foreign earned income could be excluded.

@JonCuster I meant the $25000 stipend in the US they are comparing to.

@Sursula the link was not helpful as the commentor has written it TVLE-13 2/3 approx 1300euro, while the calculator is showing 1800 euros. I am not understanding what I am getting wrong.

@BryanKrause In USA 25000USD stipend is tax free. and cost of living in that particular city is well within 1000 dollars per month as I enquired from a labmate.

@RichaSarma You're sure about that? Typically stipends would be taxed in the US. It's possible yours is not due to an agreement with your home country.

"I am not understanding what I am getting wrong." You're ignoring more than 10 years of inflation. The numbers from the linked answer are from 2013. Still, the answer contains all the relevant information - in particular, the link to the "Öffentlicher Dienst"-calculator.

Regarding the comparison to the offer in the United States: Please keep in mind that net salaries are hardly comparable between Germany and the US. In particular, the net salary in Germany is the number you get after health insurance and contributions to a pension plan have already been paid (although this pension plan comes with some caveats regarding how long you live in Germany).

@RichaSarma the calculator shows the correct numbers for today, the link to the old answer also has general information that might be helpful. Also, as an added note, do keep in mind cost of living when making a decision, in many places in the US it is more expensive to live compared to Germany.

I got it now. Thank you, you guys have been really helpful, especially @Sursula. Another thing not related to academia exactly my USA visa J1 was rejected around 5 years back, so I was particularly skeptical about USA. You guys made the decision easier. Now another matter will be declining the USA offer politely as the professor really went to different lengths to get me accepted.

From my experience with living in Germany and the US, the 1.800€/mon(after taxes and insurances)  will allow for a more comfortable life that 25.000$/year  (even if there won't e any deductions).

I cannot speak to the actual amount you will be paid, but do keep the following in mind:

Munster/Germany may not be the center of the world, but it is not a bad place either and it will not be difficult to explore Europe from there by train. Johnson City, TN -- I assume you've been there and looked also what's outside city limits? Let's just say it's not the center of the world either, and nothing around it is either.
It's hard to compare German and US salaries. You won't have to pay for health insurance there, and if you get sick you won't go broke because your deductible is negligible. You will have good public transportation. All the stuff governments that are reasonably funded can offer to you.
As many others have already pointed out on this site, pretty much everyone who has lived abroad says that that was the best decision they made in their lives. It's hard to measure the value of that by comparing salaries. (Of course, living abroad is also hard: You're far from family and friends, and in an unfamiliar environment where you might not speak the language.)


In USA also, I will have an insurance being a foreign citizen. The amount is 1750 USD for a year that I have to pay from my stipend and it's okay with me.

You might have insurance, but if you actually get sick, you might have to pay a deductible of $1000 anyway. In Germany, deductibles are minor issues.
